# Iterating over a dataframe's columns and edit the values

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
test = {'col1':[{'value': '001'},{'value': False},{'value': 'abc'}]}
df = pd.DataFrame(test)

col1
0   {'value': '001'}
1   {'value': False}
2   {'value': 'abc'}
```

I want to iterate over `col1` and only show the true values, such that I get:

```
col1
0    '001'
1    False
2   'abc'
```

I tried doing `df.replace(r'{^\d\.}+', '', regex=True)` which didn't work, I wonder what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use `.str`:

```py
>>> df['col1'].str['value']
0      001
1    False
2      abc
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

As unintuitive as it seems, `.str` can be used in just about any way than you'd use `[]` normally on. For example, the above works because this works:

```
item = df['col1'][0]
item['value'] # <---- Because this works, you can do `df['col1'].str['value']`
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(df["col1"].tolist())
   value
0    001
1  False
2    abc
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way using map:

```
df['col1'].map(lambda x: list(x.values())[0])

0      001
1    False
2      abc
Name: col1, dtype: object
```